# Migrate from Cloud SQL to DataStore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I'm creating App where I need to make Post Feeds. Right now I'm using App Engine Standard and Cloud SQL instance **db-n1-standard-1** which is based on `MySQL` But I notice it is very expensive. App is under production mode and In first month price is much higher than my expectation. Most costly thing in Cloud SQL is **instance hours rate** So, I decide to migrate it on datastore.

I have three tables, **1-** *users* **2-** *posts* **3-** *comments* And Every Table has round about **10 Millions** Rows. **Posts and Comments** table are
growing very fast 100 of millions rows are expected.

**Users Table**

```
user_id         name        email           phone
--------------------------------------------------
u123            Abc         abc@m.com       123456
u124            Cde         cde@m.com       789065
u786            Qwe         qwe@m.com       754599
 .               .              .               .
 .               .              .               .
 .               .              .               .
```

**Posts Table**

```
post_id         user_id         type        src                 date
------------------------------------------------------------------------
p098            u123            img         path/to/file        13-3-17
p456            u123            vid         path/to/file        14-3-17
p239            u124            img         path/to/file        15-3-17
 .               .               .              .                   .
 .               .               .              .                   .
 .               .               .              .                   .
```

**Comments Table**

```
cmnt_id         post_id         user_id         comment
--------------------------------------------------------
m392            p098            u123            Some Text
m234            p098            u786            Some Text
m324            p456            u123            Some Text
 .               .               .                .
 .               .               .                .
 .               .               .                .
```

As you can see `User` can post **one or more** `posts` and single `post` has
**one or more** `comments`

I need to get **posts** data along with **post comments** I know I need to use
`JOIN` for this. And I can easily use it in Cloud SQL because it's based on MySQL.

These three tables have relation between them and As I know Cloud SQL is relational database but DataStore is not.

**I have idea in my mind to convert these tables in DataStore**

1- Create Entity as `Users` and save all users records there
2- Create Entity as `Posts` and save all posts records there
3 - Create Entity as `Comments` and save all comments records there

*Post id is always I know for which post I need to get data*

For example I need post data about id `p098` I'm using **Java** I decide to create two `threads` First thread get `post` data from `Posts` Entity and second 
thread get `comment` data from `Comments` Entity. Then I merge these two data set by using java to generate same result as `JOIN` Like `MySQL`  Because I think DataStore is not allow `JOINS`

Here I need some Suggestions.

1. Is it a good way to do that ?
2. Which Provide the best Performance in this Situation ?
3. If Thousands of User(*Large Number of Users*) is accessing **Posts and Comments** data as same time
   which one can handle it better ?
4. What about Pricing Effect if I migrate from Cloud SQL to DataStore in this
   situation ?
5. If your App need continuous database then SQL instance run continuous which
   make it high cost, isn't it ?
   **For example** in my App every user when open app need to show Posts if there
   is large number of users then I think SQL instance never shutdown. Which 
   means it run **730 hr** in a month.
6. Any recommendation ?

Comment: Billions of Users?

Comment: A large number of users is using this App

Comment: Yeah, but since the population of the entire earth is shy of 8 billion....billions, really?

Comment: Oops, I just use Billion to represent large number of users. Ok, maybe in thousands

Comment: Are you using objectify?

Comment: Yes I'm using objectify

Answer (score 0):

I would put Comments as Child entity of Posts. Query by Ancestors is faster than other queries for your Join.

I might also have Posts as Child entity of User

So you end up with a structure like:

`| User, 123 |  --> | Post, 456 | --> | Comment, 789 |
 (Grand Dad)           (Dad)               (Child)`

EDIT: Tim Hoffman is right, Comment should be child of "User" and not "User > Post".

Comment: Thanks for this, but what about the others ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. What others? You only mention 3 tables right?
Each Entity Kind is "like" a table. The only difference is when you create an entity you can define an "ancestor" in its key.
Sor fo example when you create a Post, you can say that it's key is: ['User', 123, 'Post']. That means that its ancestor is "User, 123" and by not providing an id to "Post" it will be autogenerated when saved.

Comment: But as I read every ancestors are in same entity groups and entity groups store in same datastore node which make it low scale-able is it right ?

Comment: Instead of this for example we can add user_id in post entity and filter by property. Which one is good ancestor or filter by property. Because there are large number of users and large number of posts by every user. I'm worried about if entity groups are not too much scaleable.

Comment: I also asked another question you can check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088623/ancestor-relation-in-datastore

Comment: Personally I would make posts a child of the User (owner of the original post), but Comments a child of the User (Poster of comment) storing the id of the original post.  The main issue of having comments as child will limit the throughput (possibly not a problem).  But also who owns the comment ?    If comment is in reply to a comment then hold a reference to the id of parent comment.

Comment: @TimHoffman Very useful info But I'm having some problem in **ancestors** please check my another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088623/ancestor-relation-in-datastore