# Ancestor relation in datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

I have three entities: `user`, `post` and `comment`. A `user` may have multiple `posts` and a `post` may have multiple `comments`.

I know I can add ancestor relations like this:

`user(Grand Parent) post(parent) comment(child)`

I'm little bit confused about ancestors. I read from documention and searches that ancestors are used for transactions, every ancestors are in same entity group and entity groups are stored in same datastore node which makes it less scaleable. Is this right?

Is creating `user` as parent of `posts` and `post` as parent of `comments` a good thing?

Rather than this we can add one extra property in the `post` entity like `user_id` as shown in example and filter by it.

Which is better/more scalable: filter posts by ancestors or add an extra property `user_id` in the `post` Entity and filter by it?

I know both approaches can get the same results but I want to know which one is better in performance and scalability?

Sorry, I'm new in datastore.

**Update 11/4/2017**

A large number of users is using this App. It's is quite possible there are more 
than one posts per sec. But A single user can not create posts more than one per sec. But multiple user may be. As described in documentations maximum entity group write rate of 1/s. Is it still possible to use Ancestor ?

Same for comments. Multiple user can add comment in a same entity group. It's is
quite possible more than one comment in one sec.

**Ancestor Queries are faster ?**

I read in many places that ancestors queries are much faster than others.
As I know the reason why they are fast is that because it create entity group and store related data in same node. So, it require less time to get data from single node as compare to multiple nodes.

**For Example:** If `post` is store in **Asia node** and `comment` is store in **Europe node** and I want to get `posts and comments` then datastore API need to fetch two nodes to complete request. Which make it slow. Rather than if I create **ancestor** relation and make entity group which create a better performance.

But what if I don't need to get `post and comment` data at same time. If I need `post` in separate web page and `comment` in separate page.In this scenario datastore api need to fetch only one node at a time.It is not matter data save in single node or save in multiple node.   What about query performance can **ancestor** make it fast in this case ?

Comment: In general it is a good idea to ask subsequent/related questions in separate posts (eventually linking/referencing the original question as context) as they tend to diverge, complicate things and harm overall readability. I'm referring here to the `Ancestor Queries are faster ?` question, quite different from the original one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct: all ancestry-related entities are in the same entity group, which raises 2 scalability issues: data contention and maximum entity group write rate of 1/s. See somehow related [Is there an Entity Group Max Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411694/is-there-an-entity-group-max-size/46411983#46411983)

There are advantages of using ancestries and some may be willing to sacrifice scalability for them (see [What would be the purpose of putting all datastore entities in a single group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496974/what-would-be-the-purpose-of-putting-all-datastore-entities-in-a-single-group/36505769#36505769)), but IMHO not for your kind of app: I think you'll agree that it's not really critical to see every new user/post/comment in random searches **immediately** after it is created (i.e. strong consistency) - the fact that it **eventually** appears is IMHO good enough.

Simply having no ancestry at all and adding additional model properties (entity keys or even just entity key IDs for entities which never have ancestors) to allow cross-referencing entities is the more scalable approach and IMHO fits well with your app.

Comment: What's **IMHO** ? And can you please explain [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention#keep-entity-groups-small) **Note that entity groups are not required if you simply plan to reference one entity from another.**

Comment: As I know Ancestors used **Strong consistency** which is not good for **comment** system because it require more time then **Eventually consistency**. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I don't think **ancestor** queries are always fast, Please check **update** in question

Comment: Ancestor queries are not inherently faster, they are more consistent.

Comment: IMHO - in my humble opinion. I think that by entity groups the note actually refers to the ancestries - there is nothing specifically referencing the groups in the API.

Comment: Sorry if my answer suggests that some queries are faster than others - what I meant is only ancestor queries being strongly consistent vs non-ancestor queries being eventually consistent (i.e. the results reflecting very recent changes or not).

Comment: I agree. I don't think that this use-case is worth to sacrifice the scalability and performance for strong consistency and transactions. Also let Datastore automatically create the IDs for best performance and scalability. Plus: reading an entity by key is always strongly consistent, even outside a transaction (e.g. you want to read the user before accepting a new create-post request by them).

Comment: But what about if there is more than one comments or posts in one sec ?? And it is possible

Comment: Without ancestry posts and comments are not in the same entity group so you don't have a write limit - you can handle any number of posts or comments per second. That's why NOT having the ancestry is a more performant and scalable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question to ask is: Are you expecting:

- User to create Posts more than once per seconds (I doubt :)
- People to comment on a Post more than once per second (could happen)

It not, then having ancestors queries will be faster than normal queries. So it depends of your usecase. I'd go for query speed unless you know you will have thousands of comments on posts.

Comment: It is possible more than one posts and comments per sec. If yes Can I still use **Ancestor Relation** ? See update in Question

Comment: I doubt that a User will be able to create a Post in 1 second :) For the comments, you can put them under User, as @Tim Hoffman suggests in the other question. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041092/migrate-from-cloud-sql-to-datastore/47062865?noredirect=1#comment81165535_47062865)

Comment: But in most case I need to get all comments of particular post it's best to make post as parent not a user. If in this case there is more than one comments in one sec what will happen